# How to use custom storybook components on react admin application?

Tags: react-admin, storybook

I'm a newbie to react admin and storybook.

I am writing a react admin application.

Apart from react admin components, I would like to re-use some custom components I have already developed in storybook.

The problem is that these custom components use special theming that messes up with react admin theming. They have their own colors, shapes, logos, etc. In fact, when I want to use them I have to import them from '@mylibrary/ui' .

So when I try to use them I get errors like:

```
>Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'white' of undefined
    at push.../../../libs/ui/src/lib/input/Checkbox.tsx.styled_components__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default.label.withConfig.theme.theme
```

Is there a way to use this custom components in react admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it, in case anyone is interested.

Had to use a ThemeProvider to my react admin application.

Like this:

> ```
> >      <ThemeProvider theme={themeDefault}>
> >       <AdminContext dataProvider={dataProvider}>
> >         <AdminUI layout={MyLayout} theme={theme}>
> ```